# Как клонировать несколько блоков HTML на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как изменить код, чтобы я мог через js вводить количество столбцов а не просто один раз клонировать.
Мне например нужно чтобы у меня было таких div 5-10 клонов.

```js
const myList = document.getElementById('div');
const listChildren = myList;
const bananasItem = listChildren;
const bananasCopy = bananasItem.cloneNode(true);
myList.appendChild(bananasCopy);
```

```css
.div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: black;
}

li {
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="div">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Именно клонировать, или просто добавить сколько угодно блоков? А как же содержимое блоков?

Comment: Клонировать, чтобы с помощью JS я мог выбрать количество сколько мне нужно будет блоков, без добавления кнопки в коде. +содержимое в блоке смог менять (например текст)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам надо было именно сам `div` скопировать несколько раз:

```js
const myList = document.getElementById('div');

const count = 8;

for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  const myListCopy = myList.cloneNode(true);
  myList.parentNode.append(myListCopy);
}
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

li {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="div">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, какая точно у вас задача, предложу такой вариант. Смысл такой, создается функция, и в нее передается массив. В зависимости от того, сколько написали элементов массива столько и будет блоков. Тем самым сможете управлять содержимым (текстом внутри блоков). А потом вставляем это в блок `<div id="div">item</div>`

```js
function itemBlock(list) {
  let out = document.querySelector('#out')
  let item = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    item +=
      `
            <div>${list[i]}</div>
        `
  }
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item);
}
itemBlock(['Один', 'Два', 'Три'])
```

```html
<div id="div">item</div>
```